# cumsum in grouped data with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have a data frame `df` (which can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hmj2HaczvnV1l3WHVKWkdwam8/view?usp=sharing)) referred to a register of companies that looks something like this:

```
    Provider.ID        Local.Authority month year entry exit total
1  1-102642676           Warwickshire    10 2010     2    0     2
2  1-102642676                   Bury    10 2010     1    0     1
3  1-102642676                   Kent    10 2010     1    0     1
4  1-102642676                  Essex    10 2010     1    0     1
5  1-102642676                Lambeth    10 2010     2    0     2
6  1-102642676            East Sussex    10 2010     5    0     5
7  1-102642676       Bristol, City of    10 2010     1    0     1
8  1-102642676              Liverpool    10 2010     1    0     1
9  1-102642676                 Merton    10 2010     1    0     1
10 1-102642676          Cheshire East    10 2010     2    0     2
11 1-102642676               Knowsley    10 2010     1    0     1
12 1-102642676        North Yorkshire    10 2010     1    0     1
13 1-102642676   Kingston upon Thames    10 2010     1    0     1
14 1-102642676               Lewisham    10 2010     1    0     1
15 1-102642676              Wiltshire    10 2010     1    0     1
16 1-102642676              Hampshire    10 2010     1    0     1
17 1-102642676             Wandsworth    10 2010     1    0     1
18 1-102642676                  Brent    10 2010     1    0     1
19 1-102642676            West Sussex    10 2010     1    0     1
20 1-102642676 Windsor and Maidenhead    10 2010     1    0     1
21 1-102642676                  Luton    10 2010     1    0     1
22 1-102642676                Enfield    10 2010     1    0     1
23 1-102642676               Somerset    10 2010     1    0     1
24 1-102642676         Cambridgeshire    10 2010     1    0     1
25 1-102642676             Hillingdon    10 2010     1    0     1
26 1-102642676               Havering    10 2010     1    0     1
27 1-102642676               Solihull    10 2010     1    0     1
28 1-102642676                 Bexley    10 2010     1    0     1
29 1-102642676               Sandwell    10 2010     1    0     1
30 1-102642676            Southampton    10 2010     1    0     1
31 1-102642676               Trafford    10 2010     1    0     1
32 1-102642676                 Newham    10 2010     1    0     1
33 1-102642676         West Berkshire    10 2010     1    0     1
34 1-102642676                Reading    10 2010     1    0     1
35 1-102642676             Hartlepool    10 2010     1    0     1
36 1-102642676              Hampshire     3 2011     1    0     1
37 1-102642676                   Kent     9 2011     0    1    -1
38 1-102642676        North Yorkshire    12 2011     0    1    -1
39 1-102642676         North Somerset    12 2012     2    0     2
40 1-102642676                   Kent    10 2014     1    0     1
41 1-102642676               Somerset     1 2016     0    1    -1
```

My goal is to create a variable that reflects the cumulative sum of the last variable (`total`) for each `Local.Authority` and each `year`. `total` is just the difference between `entry` and `exit`. I have tried to carry out this operation by applying `dplyr` on the following basis:

```
library(dplyr)
 df.1 = df %>% group_by(Local.Authority, year) %>%
  mutate(cum.total = cumsum(total)) %>%
  arrange(year, month, Local.Authority)
```

Yielding the (wrong) result below:

```
> df.1
Source: local data frame [41 x 8]
Groups: Local.Authority, year [41]

   Provider.ID  Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.total
        <fctr>           <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1  1-102642676           Bexley    10  2010     1     0     1        35
2  1-102642676            Brent    10  2010     1     0     1        25
3  1-102642676 Bristol, City of    10  2010     1     0     1        13
4  1-102642676             Bury    10  2010     1     0     1         3
5  1-102642676   Cambridgeshire    10  2010     1     0     1        31
6  1-102642676    Cheshire East    10  2010     2     0     2        17
7  1-102642676      East Sussex    10  2010     5     0     5        12
8  1-102642676          Enfield    10  2010     1     0     1        29
9  1-102642676            Essex    10  2010     1     0     1         5
10 1-102642676        Hampshire    10  2010     1     0     1        23
..         ...              ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...       ...
```

I have confirmed these results by checking levels in the variable `Local.Authority` that appear in various years (for example Kent):

```
> check = df.1 %>% filter(Local.Authority == "Kent")
> check
Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
Groups: Local.Authority, year [3]

  Provider.ID Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.total
       <fctr>          <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1 1-102642676            Kent    10  2010     1     0     1         4
2 1-102642676            Kent     9  2011     0     1    -1        42
3 1-102642676            Kent    10  2014     1     0     1        44
```

Where it should be:

```
Provider.ID Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.total
       <fctr>          <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1 1-102642676            Kent    10  2010     1     0     1         1
2 1-102642676            Kent     9  2011     0     1    -1         0
3 1-102642676            Kent    10  2014     1     0     1         1
```

Would anyone know what may be happening for getting these results out of the cumsum? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to arrange your data frame first?

Comment: I can't reproduce. But I get the expected result on my end. The result should *not* be `1 0 1` for Kent if you group by `Local.Authority` *and* `year`; it should be `1 -1 1` (as there is only one observation per group). You get `1 0 1` should you group by Kent only: `df %>% filter(Local.Authority == "Kent") %>% group_by(Local.Authority) %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(total)) %>% .$cumsum`

Comment: @Steven is right, and this is also the result I’m getting. I forgot I had grouped by `year`, too.

Comment: @wjchulme, I have tried both options -  i.e. before and after doing the cumulative sum and always wrong results. Firstly it was yielding the cumulative without considering groups.

Comment: @Edu I think you need to use `arrange(Local.Authority, year, month)` (in that order!) before using `cumsum`

Comment: @Steven, yes, you are right. Thanks. Still, by grouping just by Local Authority I get the result from my latter comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you group by local.Authority & year it takes unique values and print the result as 1,-1,1 so better group by only local.Authority where cumsum works based on total values and result 1,0,1

```
 df <- df %>%
      group_by(Local.Authority) %>%
      mutate(cum.to = cumsum(total))

    > df
    Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
    Groups: Local.Authority [1]

      Provider.ID Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.to
            <chr>           <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
    1 1-102642676            Kent    10  2010     1     0     1      1
    2 1-102642676            Kent     9  2011     0     1    -1      0
    3 1-102642676            Kent    10  2014     1     0     1      1
```

Comment: I haven't seen the comments and started working on the code

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to my problem. I restarted my session and I got my result grouping just by Local Authority and then arranging:

```
> df.1 = df %>% group_by(Local.Authority) %>%
+ mutate(cum.total = cumsum(total)) %>%
+ arrange(year, month, Local.Authority)
> df.1
Source: local data frame [41 x 8]
Groups: Local.Authority [36]

   Provider.ID  Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.total
        <fctr>           <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1  1-102642676           Bexley    10  2010     1     0     1         1
2  1-102642676            Brent    10  2010     1     0     1         1
3  1-102642676 Bristol, City of    10  2010     1     0     1         1
4  1-102642676             Bury    10  2010     1     0     1         1
5  1-102642676   Cambridgeshire    10  2010     1     0     1         1
6  1-102642676    Cheshire East    10  2010     2     0     2         2
7  1-102642676      East Sussex    10  2010     5     0     5         5
8  1-102642676          Enfield    10  2010     1     0     1         1
9  1-102642676            Essex    10  2010     1     0     1         1
10 1-102642676        Hampshire    10  2010     1     0     1         1
```

Checking "Kent" now it yields the expected result:

```
> check = df.1 %>% filter(Local.Authority == "Kent")
> check
Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
Groups: Local.Authority [1]

  Provider.ID Local.Authority month  year entry  exit total cum.total
       <fctr>          <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1 1-102642676            Kent    10  2010     1     0     1         1
2 1-102642676            Kent     9  2011     0     1    -1         0
3 1-102642676            Kent    10  2014     1     0     1         1
```